# Firebase Firestore - delay between data is written and available for a query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have noticed a delay between the time some data is written to Firestore and when it is available to be read via a query. In my tests I see this can go up to 30sec.

- Is this documented anywhere?
- Are there ways to decrease this delay?
- Is there a way to know the server timestamp corresponding to the data being returned? Or to have any indication about this delay in the data being returned from Firestore?
  (say some data is written to the server at 1:00 - the document is created server-side at that time, I query it at 1:01, but due to the delay it returns the data as it was at 0:58 server-side, the timestamp would be 0:58)

Here I am not speaking about anything with high load, my tests were just about writing and then reading 1 small document.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore will have some delays, even I have noticed it. It's better to use the Realtime Database as it lives up to the name, the time lag is minimal, less than a second in most cases !

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firestore on a native device `offline first` is enabled by default. That means data is first written to a cache on your device and then synced to the backend. On Web you can enable that to. To listen for those changes when a `write` is saved to the backend you would need to enable `includeMetadataChanges` on your realtime listeners:

```
db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot({
        // Listen for document metadata changes
        includeMetadataChanges: true
    }, (doc) => {
        // ...
    });
```

That way you will get a notice when the data is written to the backend. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes).

The delay should be only between different devices. If you listen to the changes on your device where you write the data it will be shown immidiately.

Also something you should take care of. If you have `offline` enabled you should not await for the writes to finish. Just use them as if they are synchronous (even on web with enabled offline feature). I had that before in my code and it looked like the database was slow. By removing the await the code was running much faster.